# CSS3 issue while trying to set max-height: 100vh;

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask a question to solve an issue that I am facing while trying to build a website. I will mention now that I am a beginner and my issue may have a simple answer which I cannot see at the moment.

I am having an HTML with 2 sections. The 2nd section contains 2 divs, one with an image and another with some text. I have the text and the image placed one next to the other with `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`  and the vh of the whole section is `min-height: 100vh;`, but the div with the text is bigger than 100vh...

**This is the picture with the issue. Please note that the picture is 100vh and the div with the text is slightly bigger.**
[image: Picture is 100vh and the text is slightly bigger. That changes more and more as I resize the window.]

https://github.com/StefanMartin92/Iulia-Martin-Photography-Website.git

I am trying the make the whole section 100vh, but the div with the text is making it go crazy if I change the window size/resolution. Please help!

```
/* ABOUT SECTION */

.about {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.about-text {
  flex: 2 1 40rem;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: var(--background-color);
  color: white;
  padding: 3rem 6rem;
}
.about-text h3 {
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
  font-family: "Ruhl Medium";
  align-items: center;
}
.about-text h2 {
  font-family: "Vibes";
  padding: 2rem;
}
.about-image {
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.about-image h5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  letter-spacing: 2rem;
}
.about-image img {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;      
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<section class="about">
  <div class="about-image">
    <h5>MINIMAL</h5>
    <img src="https://stefanmartin92.github.io/Iulia-Martin-Photography-Website/img/about-image.png" alt="portrait-picture">
  </div>
  <div class="about-text flex">
    <h2>Iulia Martin</h2>
    <div class="about-life">
      <h3>My Life</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis reprehenderit nobis distinctio vel, earum sapiente, ullam fugiat deleniti dicta magni quos nam aliquam modi. Cumque esse nihil illo dolore fugit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about-work">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis reprehenderit nobis distinctio vel, earum sapiente, ullam fugiat deleniti dicta magni quos nam aliquam modi. Cumque esse nihil illo dolore fugit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about-contact">
      <h3>Get in touch</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis reprehenderit nobis distinctio vel, earum sapiente, ullam fugiat deleniti dicta magni quos nam aliquam modi. Cumque esse nihil illo dolore fugit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Research flexbox a bit more. Flexbox always uses the height of the highest element for the entire row ... asfaik align-items: strech might help to solve the issue ...

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It also would be good if you could give a code example directly here at stack overflow showcasing what the issue is, rather than posting an entire github project.

It is hard for most people to look through the entire code to find the needle in the haystack, cause of limited time ....

Comment: @mahatmanich I have added the about section style code and a picture of the issue. Please have a look!

Comment: _“but the div with the text is bigger than 100vh...”_ -  it _obviously_ needs more space, than the min-height you specified offers – so it gets extended accordingly. If you do not want that - then you either need to reduce the size of that content (smaller margins/paddings, font-size, less text …) - or explain what _else_ you wanted it to do in that situation then.

Comment: If you take out a line of every lorem ipsum then it might already work ...  can you also post the html please!

Comment: @mahatmanich you have the html attached!

Comment: Have you tried:
.about {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min-height` sets just that, the minimum height of an element. It can still be bigger if it needs to, and that it is bigger. I don't know what exactly you want for this, but if you want it to scroll you can use.

```css
max-height: 100vh;
overflow: scroll
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make the div with the text the same size as the div with the picture and not scroll to see all the text.

Comment: then you will need less content, or smaller font